# Quiz How to submit answers and score it

Tags: php

I have 10 question at a time on a page quiz.html-     i.e

**question 1:**
 what is your name?

```
<option value="a">a</option>   
<option va..>b</option>...    
<option va...>e</option>
```

**question 2:**
 what are the colors in usa flag?

```
<option>a</option>
```

and so on.

My question is how do i submit this question at a time and add `+1` into the score field in the database for each correct answer?

I can do the saving and scoring if there is only 1 question per page i.e

```
select * from quiz where id='qid'
```

then

```
while($fetch=mysql_fetch_row($query)){
    if( $fetch["answer"]==$useranswer ){ add +1 to his score; }
}
```

But for many question i don't know what to do.

The structure of the html is:

```
<form action="quizer.php" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="q1" value="qid"> what is your name? 
    <option value="a">rolex</option>
    <option value="b">wales</option>
    <option value="c">israel</option>
    <option value="d">ade</option>

    <br>
    <input type="hidden" name="q2" value="qid"> 
    is nigeria a country?
    <option value="a">no</option>
    <option value="b">yes</option>

    and so on... 
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: how is the table structure for quiz? how is the user score like? combined for current question? combined for all question including answered question? what is the expected result?

Comment: The table quiz has fields..    <code>id,question,optionA,optionB,optionC,optionD, correct_answer</code>     then in the table user i have a field which will hold the score.      If users finished attempting the questions and clicks submit, how do i get each user selected option and then update table user the incrementing score as per user correct selected option

Comment: You might need to share some of the html too - how are the fields named?

Comment: how are you fetching your question? through the db using a while statement? u probably will use that as well to do the same for insert, but with 2 more argument. show you edit your question with your full php code for the code that will do the scoring?

Comment: gosh, can you edit your question? and also your php code.

Comment: <input type="hidden" name="q2" value="qid"> your 'qid' same for all question? are you are just trying to give an example? I think if you want us to help you, you have to help us figure out where the problem lies and answer our question. Can you show your full code from starting from <form> until the end for html, and your full php code. you can omit the conn param

Comment: Your html is missing the `select` tags if these are to be dropdown menus - otherwise, if they are radio buttons then again - the tags are missing

Comment: Thanks..Yea i know...just to shorten time...any help please

Comment: @mark yea..just an example

Comment: I am not looking at it any more until you edit your question with what I require from you to possibly help you. I can't guess what those missing are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the questions are using select menus as you sort of suggested then this should help - though it is not tested...

```
<?php
    /* quizer.php */
    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' ){
        /* select correct answers from db */
        $sql='select * from `quiz`';
        $res=mysql_query( $sql, $con );

        /* store answers in an array for marking */
        $answers=array();
        $score=0;
        $index=0;

        /* populate the answers array */
        while( $rs=mysql_fetch_object( $res ) ){
            $answers[]=$rs->correct_answer;
        }

        /* mark the answers */
        foreach( $_POST as $question => $answer ){
            echo $question.' '.$answer;
            if( $answer === $answers[ $index ] ) $score++;
            $index++;
        }
        /* update the db */
        $sql="update `user` set `score`=$score where `username`='$username';"; /* etc */
    }
?>



<form action="quizer.php" method="post">
    <!-- assume select menus for questions and possible answers -->
    <label for='q1'>what is your name? 
        <select name='q1'>
            <option value="a">rolex</option>
            <option value="b">wales</option>
            <option value="c">israel</option>
            <option value="d">ade</option>
        </select>
    </label>

    <br />

    <label for='q2'>is nigeria a country?
        <select name='q2'>
            <option value="a">no</option>
            <option value="b">yes</option>
        </select>
    </label>

    <br />

    <input type="submit" value='Submit Quiz'>
</form>
```

Comment: I have tested and it all seems to work ~ the only difference was that I used mysqli rather than mysql ( which, btw, is deprecated and should no longer be used! ) - if it helps, accept the answer '-)